# How to configure viewport addon for Angular

Tags: angular, storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

According to [this documentation](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/tree/master/addons/viewport#add-new-device) i am trying add custom viewport in conifig.js file:

```
import { addParameters } from '@storybook/angular'; // changing from react to angular
import { INITIAL_VIEWPORTS } from '@storybook/addon-viewport';

const newViewports = {
  kindleFire2: {
    name: 'Kindle Fire 2',
    styles: {
      width: '600px',
      height: '963px',
    },
  },
  kindleFireHD: {
    name: 'Kindle Fire HD',
    styles: {
      width: '533px',
      height: '801px',
    },
  },
};

addParameters({
  viewport: {
    viewports: {
      ...INITIAL_VIEWPORTS,
      ...newViewports,
    },
  },
});
```

But it not works for me because in angular lib we do not have implementation for addParameters method. How can we configure this for angular?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the spread operator on Storybook, so, to fix this on an Angular app you should install the `transform-object-rest-spread` plugin and configure Babel on Playbook.

You can follow the next steps:

1. Install the plugin: `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`.
2. Create the file `.babelrc` under the folder `.storybook/` (*No worries, Babel, in this case, will only affect Playbook configuration. Here's more info https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-babel-config/*)
3. Add the next code on the file `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

4. Wrap the Viewports object on an object o generate a new object:

**Option A**

```js
viewport: { viewports: {...INITIAL_VIEWPORTS, ...newViewports} }
```

**Option B**

```js
const myViewports = {...INITIAL_VIEWPORTS, ...newViewports};

addParameters({ viewport: { viewports: myViewports} });
```

5. Run Storybook again and enjoy ;)

Hope this works!

Comment: I didn't need to do any of this on my project (part of a Nrwl NX workspace). I just had to add the missing "type" property to the Viewport definitions.